# Why Python append function does not work in this case?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to find the indices of the misclassified samples using the following code. But I found that the append function does not actually append the index. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

```
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    misclassified_indices = []
    if y_test[i] != predictions[i]:
        print(i)
        misclassified_indices.append(i)
        
print(misclassified_indices)
```

```
19
357
1553     # All misclassified samples are printed correctly ...
[]       # ... but it does not append to this list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initially assign your list outside the loop:

```
misclassified_indices = []
for i in range(len(predictions)):
```

In your original code, `misclassified_indices` is reassigned back to an empty list on every loop iteration, which causes it to be empty at the end.

You can also shorten your code using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
misclassified_indices = [i for i in range(len(predictions)) if y_test[i] != predictions[i]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you reset the misclassified_indices to [] inside the loop. Just move your second line to outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

try to put the list outside of the loop:

```
misclassified_indices = [] # <-- goes here
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    
    if y_test[i] != predictions[i]:
        print(i)
        misclassified_indices.append(i)
        
print(misclassified_indices)
```